# Given a block number, how do I find the block hash using Nethereuem?

Tags: blocks, nethereum

Using Nethereum, I would like to get the block hash given a block number (i.e. block height).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works

```
    blockHash = (await _web3.Eth.Blocks.GetBlockWithTransactionsByNumber.SendRequestAsync(
        new HexBigInteger(relevantBlockNumber))).BlockHash;
```